# If $f$ is bounded Riemann integrable over $[a,b],$ then there is $\{P_n\}$ of partitions with $\lim_{n\to\infty}[U(f,P_n]-L(f,P_n)]=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, riemann-integration

The following question is taken from Real Analysis by Royden, Chapter $4,$ question $4:$

> Suppose the bounded functoin $f$ on $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable over $[a,b].$
>       Show that there is a  sequence $\{P_n\}$ of partitions of $[a,b]$ for which $\lim_{n\to\infty}[U(f,P_n]-L(f,P_n)]=0.$

My attempt:

Fix a natural number $n.$
    Then there exists two sequences of partitions $\{P_n'\}$ and $\{P_n''\}$ of $[a,b]$ such that 
    $$\overline{\int}_a^b f-\frac{1}{n}\leq L(f,P_n') \leq \underline{\int}_a^b f = \overline{\int}_a^b f \leq  U(f,P_n'') < \overline{\int}_a^b f + \frac{1}{n}.$$
Let $P_n = P_n'\cup P_n''.$
Then $P_n$ is a refinement of $P_n'$ and $P_n''.$
Therefore, 
$$L(f,P'_n) \leq L(f,P_n) \leq \overline{\int}_a^b f$$
and 
$$\overline{\int}_a^b f \leq U(f,P_n) \leq U(f,P_n'').$$
    Hence,
    $$\lim_{n\to\infty}[U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_n) ] \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2}{n} = 0.$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You can't really guarantee that $P_n$'s in $$\underline{\int}^b_a f - \frac 1n < L(f,P_n)$$ and in $$U(f,P_n)< \overline{\int}^b_a f + \frac1n$$ are the same one. From the definition, you can `only` find a $P_n$ for the first inequality, and a $P^\prime_n$ for the second. The exercise asks you to `merge` the two partitions into one.

Comment: @QuangHoang: Edited. Is it okay now?

Comment: Yes, it is now.